# Why does my Java app run faster with profiler attached?

Tags: java, opencv, netbeans, jvm, profiling

I am developing a Java 8 SE application in Netbeans. A new feature I added recently to the app was running too slowly (about a minute, until the calculations stopped). So I fired up the profiler to see what is the major bottleneck. To my surprise, the calculations completed in about 7 seconds.

Couldn't believe it at first, but the results were correct.
Tried it a few times again, but the app always ran 10 times faster with the profiler attached to it. I also tried to run the compiled .jar file directly from the Windows command line, but the computations took about a minute again and again.

How is it possible, that the attached profiler provides such a massive boost to the performance? What changes does it do to the JVM or application?

BTW, I am using native OpenCV in these calculations with provided Java wrapper, if it makes any difference.

//Edit - Additional info: I am using the built-in Netbeans 8.1 profiler, which I believe is basically VisualVM. As for a profiling method I chose to monitor "Methods" and their execution times and invocation counts. The performance bump happens both with instrumented and sampled profiling.

Comment: I think your question might be better refined from "why is the profiler environment faster" to "why is the non-profiler environment slower".

Comment: What profiler do you use? `What changes does it do to the JVM or application?` can only be answered if you give that information because there are different profiling techniques (sampling, instrumentation, ...) ;)

Comment: @Markus Weninger I updated the post with some info

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there probably isn't one single answer that will explain why this is the case. Of course, it will depend on what the program is doing as well as how the program is being launched. For example, if you're using the profiler to launch the application (as opposed to connecting afterwards) then it may be that the profiler is launching with different configuration (heap size, garbage collector etc.) and that is the cause of the difference.

If you run `jcmd` you should see a list of processes. You can then run `jcmd <id> VM.flags` to see what the JVM has been configured with, and verify that the same are for the application when under a profiler and when it isn't.

Another possibility is that your program is excessively locking, and this excessive locking is causing thrashing in your application when the profiler isn't attached. With it attached the locking may be slower, resulting in the application threads co-operating and ultimately making faster progress.

However these are just suggestions of how you can investigate further; it's quite likely that there is another as yet undiscovered problem that you're seeing which is completely different (e.g. it's defaulting to a different level of logging ...)